# Selecting values where the first 6 characters match

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to pull a list of IDs from a table Company where the first 6 characters of the ID are the same. The way our application creates a company ID is it takes the first 3 characters of the company name and the first 3 characters of the City. Beceause of that, overtime we have company IDs with the same first 6 characters, followed by a sequential number...

I was thinking using something using LIKE

```
Select companyID, companyName from Company Where
substring(companyID,1,6)+'%' like substring(companyID,1,6)+'%'
```

Basically i'm trying to get all company IDs where the first 6 characters match; The result set should show the just the top company ID ( The first 1 created) and the company name. I'm not expecting a tone of results, so i can then use the IDs returned to find the IDs below it.

I'm thinking it could maybe also be done using HAVING, where the count of IDs with the same first 6 characters are the same HAVING Count(*)>1??
Not really sure what the syntax would be...

Comment: Simply join the table to itself and then compare the company names.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After trying to use Blam's script, i made a few slight changes and got some better results. His script was returning more results than rows in the table and it was pretty slow; think it's because of the company_name column. I got rid of it and wrote it like this:

```
select distinct c1.cmp_id, count(substring(c2.cmp_id,1,6)) as TotalCount
from company c1
join company c2 on substring(c1.cmp_id,1,6)=substring(c2.cmp_id,1,6)
group by c1.cmp_id
order by c1.cmp_id asc
```

This still returns all the table records, but atleast i can see the total count when the first 6 characters are listed more than once. Also, it ran in only 1 second so that's also a plus. Thank again for you input guys, always appreciated!

Comment: The stated question is "the result set should show the just the top company ID ( The first 1 created) and the company name".  This solution does not return company name.  How is a solution that does not meet the question as stated better results?

Comment: I also asked "i'm trying to get all company IDs where the first 6 characters match". Not trying to start an argument, but that's a dumb reason to -1 me. I answered my own question using your answer as a refference and posted what worked best for me on my own thread...

Comment: "The result set should show the just the top company ID ( The first 1 created) and the company name."  Your words not mine.

Comment: Way to show support for new users; Sorry i didn't OCD over every word in my thread.

Comment: OCD?   Those are the words in your thread.   Way to show support for those that answer the stated question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct c1.CompanyID, c1.CompanyName, c2.CompanyID, c2.CompanyName
  FROM dbo.Company c1
  JOIN dbo.Company c2
    ON SUBSTRING(c1.CompanyName,1,6) = SUBSTRING(c2.CompanyName,1,6) 
   AND c1.CompanyID < c2.CompanyID
 order by c1.CompanyName, c2.CompanyName
```

Comment: Thank you! I should be able to work with these results. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c1.CompanyID, c1.CompanyName, c2.CompanyID, c2.CompanyName
FROM dbo.Company c1
INNER JOIN dbo.Company c2
ON SUBSTRING(c1.CompanyName,1,6) + '%' LIKE SUBSTRING(c2.CompanyName,1,6) + '%'
AND c1.CompanyID <> c2.CompanyID
```

Comment: why the overhead of a like.  Still +1

Comment: You're right, should be using = like your answer.  I just copied and pasted from above.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that you envision doing frequently, I'd add a computed column to the table that has a definition of `substring(CompanyName, 1, 6)`. You can then index it and make this efficient. As it is, it will have to scan all the entries and calculate the substring on the fly. With the computed column, you amortize the substring calculation up front and at least have a chance at an efficient query.